# How to change top bar when working with bottom navigation

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm making my application based on the standard Bottom Navigation Activity
from Android Studio.The code was generated automatically, I didn't change it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
}
```

And I have this:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fky4N.png)

I want to add to the top screen an icon,
by which I will go to other fragments of the MainActivity (which are not in the bottom menu).
I want to have this on top of screen
[top bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmqUo.png)

1. How can I place them exactly on top?
2. How can I change the color of this top bar?

So far, I could only programmatically set the Title in onCreate MainActivity
like this (after deleting labels in mobile_navigations):

```
this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TEST");
```

Comment: you can  remove the toolbar in activity and use separate toolbar for each fragment

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How to do it? What code should be added to the activity, what code should be added to the fragments?

Comment: @Kharin1986 follow this link https://medium.com/@qureshi.ayaz29/custom-toolbar-in-android-3818a0740942

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. override onCreateOptionsMenu() in MainActivity.

   ```java
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu)
        return true
    }
   ```
2. create menus in res folder

   ```xml
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <item android:id="@+id/menu_next"
           android:title="toNext"
           android:titleCondensed="next"
           android:orderInCategory="1"
           android:icon="your icon"
           app:showAsAction="always" />
   </menu>
   ```

[menu api](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus)